# How to sort an object array by two different values

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

I have an object array

```
var arr= [  {vara:4, varb:0, varc:3}    {vara:1, varb:2, varc:0}    {vara:3, varb:1, varc:5} ..... ]
```

At first i want to sort the array by vara so i use

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){return a.vara-b.vara});
```

If the sorted array have equal values in vara parameter, i want to do a second sorting by varb that will only resort the objects with equal vara values and not all the array.

How is this possible?

Comment: Are your values always integers?

Comment: in this case they are..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    if (a.vara === b.vara) {
        return a.varb - b.varb
    }
    return a.vara-b.vara;
});
```